# Ionic - get historical geolocation data from a user's device?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm building an Ionic application in which I'd like to access not a user's current location, but their location history. In specific, I'd like to access their location history between two given datetimes.

Has anyone built something like this before with Ionic?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get historical user location, you need to save current user location every 5 or x minutes in database (Maybe Firebase) and then retrieve the data.
[Check this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-add-location-history/10792/3)

Comment: Good to know and thanks for providing an alternative solution Nahuel